# Displaying 4 products per slide page using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to create a slider using carousel and I want 4 items to be diplayed per slide.Data will be transferred in `json` format  from a database table.For now I have this php script but I think I must change some parts to do the job.

```
$stmt_select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `gifts` LIMIT 0,4;");
    $stmt_select->execute();

    if($stmt_select->rowCount() > 0) {
        $json = array();
        while ($row_select = $stmt_select->fetch()){

        $json[] = array(
        'image' => $row_select['image'],
        'title' => $row_select['title'],
        'description' => $row_select['description']

        );
        }

        echo json_encode($json);
    }
```

and this is the script that loads json

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_json.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_param: 'value'},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // check with console
            console.log(data);

            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $('#output').append('<li class="caption"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="item_img"><img src="' +item.image+ '" /></div><div class="item_title">"' +item.title+ '"</div><div class="item_descr">'+ item.description +'</div></div></li>');

                });
            }
        });
```

Any ideas how can I make it happen?

Comment: What is the issue/improvement you want to do ?

Comment: I think that your code is OK, any problems?

Comment: Fox example if I have 9 transactions in my database table I want this to be displayed.4 items >(hit on arrow slide) 4 items >(hit on arrow slide) 1 item.I think i will need a `for...loop` to make it possible but I cannot figure this out.The php script below brings only 4 rows even if I have 100..

Comment: The if-statement is not necessary. Right now the behaviour is undefined when the rowcount is 0, while you probably want to have an empty array returned if that is the case. To better help you we need to have the debug information. What does `console.log(..)` log for example?

Comment: Helps me checking if the json sends proper data to `html`.Nothing more..It could be removed

Comment: The PHP only returns 4 rows because of the LIMIT clause in the SQL statement, I think. Probably the solution is to return all the rows to the client, and then in the javascript you should create the HTML appropriately so that it displays them in groups of 4

Comment: Any ideas?I am trying but still nothing